# How to remove the gap on piechart slice with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

[image]

I am using highchart , and there is a gap there in the red frame.(between 2 slice) How can I remove it ?

Comment: set `sliced` to false, see: https://jsfiddle.net/0oy34jpd/   and   https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#sliced

Comment: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.data.selected

Answer (score 0):

Set `plotOptions.pie.borderWidth = 0;`

inside options like below:

```
{
   plotOptions: {
     pie: {
       borderWidth: 0
     }
   }

}
```